# Position of 5 JPanels

Tags: java, jpanel, border-layout

** I am new to Java!

I have 5 JPanels and I want them to be placed like that [image]

This is what I have so far:

```
add(panel1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
add(panel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(panel3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(panel4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
add(panel5, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

they are overlapping each other and some one them are not showing. How can I fix it.

### Is there anything other than BorderLayout that can be used?

Sorry but this chapter was explained in one session. My main issue is that I don`t understand what I can replace the BorderLayout.X with.

Here`s what I have so far:

```
private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1,0,0));


JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), 
            "title2", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));



JPanel panel2= new JPanel();
panel2.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), 
            "title", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
contentPane.add(panel2);
panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,0,0));
```

---

```
add(panel1);
add(panel2);
add(panel3);
add(panel4);
```

My layout is set to gridLayout, now when adding the panels what should I write add(panel1, ???)?

Comment: Look at the description of `BorderLayout` and you'll see that it doesn't fit your design (it has one slot at top and bottom as well as one at left and right and a center one) - PAGE_START and NORTH are basically the same. What you want is `GridLayout` with 1 column or `FlowLayout`.

Comment: Could also use a BoxLayout

Comment: `GridBagLayout` - see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: @reddit_10 are you setting `contentPane` to your frame?

Comment: @ReşitDönük omg I didn`t notice that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GridLayout`. Wtih `GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)` constructor you can define vertical and horizontal gaps.

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1, 0, 5));
```

And according to your update; you must set `contentPane` to your frame.

```
frame.setContentPane(contenPane);
```

Comment: Then, constraints are not necessary. add panels like this: `add(panel1);`

Comment: I did, check the code, I updated the post. thank you